# Symfony 2.5 : sql query with Where IN Clause using an array as a parameter

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to run sql query. I am trying to select users with specific roles.
Below my query:

```
  $roleUser= $this->container->getParameter('user_role');

  $query = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
      ->createQuery(
          'SELECT u FROM UserBundle:User ur
          WHERE ur.role  IN :role_user')
     ->setParameters('role_user',$roleUser);
```

In my config.yml I defined my user roles

```
parameters:
  user_role:
   - ADMIN1
   - ADMIN2
   - ADMIN3
```

I want to select all the user that has one of the role ADMIN1, ADMIN2 or ADMIN3.

Here is the error message:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Test/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query.php line 246
{
    $types = array();
    foreach ($this->parameters as $parameter) {
        /** @var Query\Parameter $parameter */
        $types[$parameter->getName()] = $parameter->getType();
    }
```

Comment: How are you storing the `ur.role` ? Is this a separate entity or it's a column inside the `User` table?

Comment: Its a colum inside the `user` table

Comment: I think you should probably `$roleUser = implode(',', $this->container->getParameter('user_role'));` instead of actually passing the array directly.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `setParameter` instead of `setParameters`:

try this:

```
 ->setParameter('role_user',$roleUser);
```

instead of this:

```
 ->setParameters('role_user',$roleUser);
```

More info about setting parameters [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#binding-parameters-to-your-query) in the doc.

Hope this help